# Border around multiline text in a div (html/css)

Tags: html, css, text, border, multiline

I want to have a border around multiline text, I have:

```
Morbi hendrerit pretium nibh quis <span style='border: 1px solid black;'>
mattis. Blah blah blah</span> blah blah...
```

Now, when the span spans more than one line, the border is created around each line of text, which I don't want to happen - I am aiming for a border around a whole block, with the text being inline (display:block/inline-block don't do the job properly).

Is there a way of achieving that without playing with javascript?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want. Where are the multiple lines you're talking about? I see one line, no <br>'s involved.

Comment: It seems you just want a block of multiline text to be inlined. I.e. an inline div with its own paragraph. Right?

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the whole string in a div and set it to display: inline-block.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; display: inline-block">
  Morbi hendrerit pretium nibh quis<br>
  mattis. Blah blah blah blah blah...
</div>
```

Comment: Or use <div>, instead of applying the display:block to the span.

Comment: Errrr... also remove that close span tag that I forgot to remove from your text when I pasted it in... The one right after the "Blah blah blah".

Comment: Yea, I noticed. However, I just tested your solution and the result is the same - every line has a border on top and on its bottom.

Comment: Or it is in a block, which I don't want to happen;)

Comment: Landed here years later.... and `<div style="display:inline-block">` worked!  I had to add the `!important` due to the conflict with another CSS setting, so that may have been effigiem's problem with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div>` instead of `<span>.` It might fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What about using an inline div instead of a span?

```
Morbi hendrerit pretium nibh quis <div class="inline-border"> mattis. 
Blah blah blah</div> blah blah...
```

and in your CSS

```
.inline-border {border: 1px solid black;display:inline}
```

Comment: Nope, the border is still on the bottom and on top of every line.